# How to fix '/' in caffinated moudule in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, url, laravel-5.3

1. I make a fresh setup of laravel on localhost (`/var/www/html/`) with command `composer create-project laravel/laravel moduleTesting --prefer-dist`.
2. Then I move all the files inside folder to (`/var/www/moduleTesting/setup`), then move all the files from public folder(`/var/www/moduleTesting/setup/public`) to moduleTesting folder(`/var/www/html/moduleTesting`).
3. I changed bootstrap file path in index.php file placed in moduleexample.dev folder(`/var/www/html/moduleTesting/`).

   require **DIR**.'/setup/bootstrap/autoload.php';
   $app = require_once **DIR**.'/../../laravel_setup/bootstrap/app.php';
4. I also set the permission of folder `/var/www/moduleTesting/setup/bootstrap/cache` and `/var/www/moduleTesting/setup/storage`
5. Then I run command `composer dump-autoload` in terminal at (`/var/www/moduleTesting/`).
6. Then I try to run URL in the browser, and I see the welcome page of laravel app.
7. Then I install module package caffeinated/modules 
   Begin by installing the package through Composer.

   ```
   composer require caffeinated/modules
   ```

   Once this operation is complete, simply add both the service provider and facade classes to project `/var/www/html/moduleTesting/setup/config/app.php` file:

   #### Service Provider

   ```
   Caffeinated\Modules\ModulesServiceProvider::class,
   ```

   #### Facade

   ```
   'Module' => Caffeinated\Modules\Facades\Module::class,
   ```
8. After successful installation, I create a new module by command 
   `make:module Admin` and follow easy steps steps and it created successfully and run by hitting URL http://localhost/moduleTesting/admin'.

## Issue

Now the problem is when I run URL.'http://localhost/moduleTesting/admin'
it runs successfully but when i run 'http://localhost/moduleTesting/admin'(add '/' only at the end of the same url) it does now work and redirect me to url 'http://localhost/admin'

Does anybody know, please help me how to solve this issue, On the same node if upload the setup on the server in a inner folder and run the same url it also redirect me.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably because .htaccess redirects *trailing slashes* to an URL without a traling slash.

In this section in your .htaccess file, Apache redirects everything with a trailing slash - if not a folder - to its origin. This causes trouble, because the public of the project is located at a directory.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]
```

Replace the second rule with:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /moduleTesting/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Note: it is better not using a directory as your public destination because these kinds of problems occur. You should be better of creating a fake local domain, like: module-test.dev or something.

Comment: Thank you for your immediate response to my question, and I edit the '.htaccess' file placed at `/var/www/html/moduleTesting` but it does not work. it is still redirecting me. I am trying for given second option for creating a new virtualhost and domain name.

Comment: You could also try adding RewriteBase /moduleTesting/ directly after RewriteEngine On (and undo my previous suggestion), maybe this will work. But creating a VH is obviously the best option indeed.